# how to return result after OpenWithCompletionHandler: is complete

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, block

Want to query a photo in the Coredata database

this is my code

this is the NSObjectSubclass category

```
//Photo+creak.h

#import "Photo+creat.h"

@implementation Photo (creat)

+(Photo *)creatPhotoByString:(NSString *)photoName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    Photo *picture = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", photoName];

    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    if (!matches || [matches count]>1) {
        //error
    } else if ([matches count] == 0) {
        picture = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        picture.name = photoName;
    } else {
        picture = [matches lastObject];
    }
    return picture;
}

+ (BOOL)isPhoto:(NSString *)photoName here:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", photoName];
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    switch ([matches count]) {
        case 1:
            return YES;
            break;
        default:
            return NO;
            break;
    }
}
@end
```

code inside of view controller

```
//View Controller
- (IBAction)insertData:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];
    UIManagedDocument *defaultDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        [defaultDocument saveToURL:defaultDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:NULL];
    }
    [defaultDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        [Photo creatPhotoByString:@"test" inManagedObjectContext:defaultDocument.managedObjectContext];
        [defaultDocument saveToURL:defaultDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
    }];
    [sender setTitle:@"Okay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}

- (IBAction)queryFromDatabase:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];
    UIManagedDocument *defaultDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    BOOL isItWorking = [checkPhoto isPhoto:@"test" inManagedDocument:defaultDocument];
    if (isItWorking) {
        [sender setTitle:@"Okay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [sender setTitle:@"NO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

The NSObject Class that hook them up.

```
 //  checkPhoto.m
#import "checkPhoto.h"
@implementation checkPhoto
+ (BOOL)isPhoto:(NSString *)photoToCheck inManagedDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document{
    __block BOOL isPhotoHere = NO;
    if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            isPhotoHere = [Photo isPhoto:photoToCheck here:document.managedObjectContext];
        }];
    }
    return isPhotoHere;
}
@end
```

The coredata only have on Entity named "Photo", and it got only one attribute "name".
The problem is that the return always get execute before the block is complete and always return NO. 
Test code [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B519iRTC07VBUF84ZHVVSVFkcVk)

**Or should I do something else than openWithCompletionHandler when querying?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rework your method to work asynchronously, like `-openWithCompletionHandler:`. It needs to take a block which is invoked when the answer is known and which receives the answer, true or false, as a parameter.

Then, the caller should pass in a block that does whatever is supposed to happen after the answer is known.

Or, alternatively, you should delay the whole chunk of logic which cares about the photo being in the database. It should be done after the open has completed.

You'd have to show more code for a more specific suggestion.

---

So, you could rework the `isPhoto...` method to something like:

```
+ (BOOL)checkIfPhoto:(NSString *)photoToCheck isInManagedDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document handler:(void (^)(BOOL isHere))handler {
    if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            handler([Photo isPhoto:photoToCheck here:document.managedObjectContext]);
        }];
    }
    else
        handler(NO);
}
```

Then you can rework this:

```
- (IBAction)queryFromDatabase:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];
    UIManagedDocument *defaultDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    [checkPhoto checkIfPhoto:@"test" isInManagedDocument:defaultDocument handler:^(BOOL isHere){
        if (isHere) {
            [sender setTitle:@"Okay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [sender setTitle:@"NO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to read through your whole project. Show the specific code that cares about the photo being in the database.

Comment: you are right...:) But, I have no idea how to fix it. can you take a look at this [Test Code](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B519iRTC07VBUF84ZHVVSVFkcVk)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't meant to post the whole project, I'm not quiet familiar with stackoverflow. I was editing the post and hit return assuming it will start a new line. sorry if it seem rude.;)

Comment: It's OK. Perhaps your best bet would be to edit your question and add the additional code there, similar to how you already added the code in your original question.

Comment: thanks a lot, how about now? it's pretty much everything in the [test code](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B519iRTC07VBUF84ZHVVSVFkcVk). (since I don't know where the problem should be, I have no idea which code to post. Only thing i can do is to create a new project and write  it again. it only have 3 set of files in it. cmd+s can save the zip file. I know it's too much to ask, but can you help me fix it)

Comment: I've updated my answer with one possible way to rework your code for asynchronicity.

Comment: thanks so much, I real hope I would vote you up a lot more than just one.;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12105/discussion-between-kyle-fang-and-ken-thomases)

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
+(BOOL)isPhoto:(Photo *)photo inDataBase:(UIManagedDocument *)defaultDocument{
 __block BOOL isPhotoThere = NO;
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[defaultDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    [defaultDocument.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        isPhotoThere = [Photo checkPhoto:photo];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];
 }];
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
 dispatch_release(sema);
 return isPhotoThere;
}
```

Comment: This *may* work or it may not if `-openWithCompletionHandler:` depends on the calling thread running its run loop.

Comment: sadly no, it froze. I seems like there are both in the same thread, it's really wired. Can you take a look at it? [code](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B519iRTC07VBUF84ZHVVSVFkcVk)

Comment: @KyleFang it probably uses NSRunLoop, so it requires the current tick of the UI to finish before the block is executed.