# Passing a Value Asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

I have the following method that uses blocks and completion handlers:

```
    // Returns YES if photo is stored in a virtual vacation.
- (BOOL) photoIsOnVacation
{
    __block BOOL photoOnFile = NO;

    // Identify the documents folder URL.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *errorForURLs      = nil;
    NSURL *documentsURL        = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                     inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                            appropriateForURL:nil
                                                       create:NO
                                                        error:&errorForURLs];
    if (documentsURL == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Could not access documents directory\n%@", [errorForURLs localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        // Retrieve the vacation stores on file.
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLLocalizedNameKey, nil];
        NSArray *vacationURLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentsURL
                                                              includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                                                                 options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                                                   error:nil];
        if (!vacationURLs) photoOnFile = NO;
        else {

            // Search each virtual vacation for the photo.
            for (NSURL *vacationURL in vacationURLs) {
                NSError *errorForName  = nil;
                NSString *vacationName = nil;
                [vacationURL getResourceValue:&vacationName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:&errorForName];
                [VacationHelper openVacationWithName:vacationName usingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *vacationDocument) {
                    NSError *error              = nil;
                    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = vacationDocument.managedObjectContext;

                    // Build fetch request.
                    NSFetchRequest *request          = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
                    NSString *currentPhotoID         = [self.chosenPhoto objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_ID];
                    request.predicate                = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"unique = %@", currentPhotoID];
                    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"unique" ascending:YES];
                    request.sortDescriptors          = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

                    // Execute fetch request.
                    NSArray *checkPhotos = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error searching for photo:%@",error);
                    } else {
                        Photo *checkPhoto = [checkPhotos lastObject];
                        if ([checkPhoto.unique isEqualToString:currentPhotoID]) photoOnFile = YES;
                    }
                }];
                if (photoOnFile) break;
            }
        }
    }
    return photoOnFile;
}
```

My problem is that photoOnFile is always false because execution reaches the return before the block that contains the fetch request.  I've tried embedding the photoOnFile assignment within dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{ but that hasn't helped.  Any guidance appreciated.

Update: here is the reworked code successfully incorporating Ken's recommended solution:

```
    - (void)checkIfPhotoIsOnVacationAndDo:(void(^)(BOOL photoIsOnVacation))completionBlock
{
    __block BOOL photoIsOnVacation = NO;

    // Identify the documents folder URL.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *errorForURLs      = nil;
    NSURL *documentsURL        = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                     inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                            appropriateForURL:nil
                                                       create:NO
                                                        error:&errorForURLs];
    if (documentsURL == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Could not access documents directory\n%@", [errorForURLs localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        // Retrieve the vacation stores on file.
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLLocalizedNameKey, nil];
        NSArray *vacationURLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentsURL
                                                              includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                                                                 options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                                                   error:nil];
        if (!vacationURLs) photoIsOnVacation = NO;
        else {

            // Search each virtual vacation for the photo.
            for (NSURL *vacationURL in vacationURLs) {
                NSError *errorForName  = nil;
                NSString *vacationName = nil;
                [vacationURL getResourceValue:&vacationName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:&errorForName];
                [VacationHelper openVacationWithName:vacationName usingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *vacationDocument) {
                    NSError *error              = nil;
                    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = vacationDocument.managedObjectContext;

                    // Build fetch request.
                    NSFetchRequest *request          = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
                    NSString *currentPhotoID         = [self.chosenPhoto objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_ID];
                    request.predicate                = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"unique = %@", currentPhotoID];
                    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"unique" ascending:YES];
                    request.sortDescriptors          = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

                    // Execute fetch request.
                    NSArray *checkPhotos = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error searching for photo:%@",error);
                    } else {
                        Photo *checkPhoto = [checkPhotos lastObject];
                        if ([checkPhoto.unique isEqualToString:currentPhotoID]) {
                            photoIsOnVacation = YES;
                            completionBlock(photoIsOnVacation);
                        }
                    }
                }];
                if (photoIsOnVacation) break;
            }
            completionBlock(photoIsOnVacation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronicity tends to spread. Once you make an API asynchronous, all of its callers have to be redesigned to work asynchronously, too. Therefore, a method like your `- (BOOL) photoIsOnVacation` is untenable because its interface is synchronous – the caller expects to have an answer as soon as the call completes – but the implementation doesn't work that way.

You have to redesign to something like `- (void) checkIfPhotoIsOnVacationAndDo:(void(^)(BOOL photoIsOnVacation))block`. That takes a block from the caller and invokes the block with the answer when it is known.

Comment: Thanks, Ken, I appreciate the guidance.  I've certainly noticed the tendency for metastasizing asynchronicity.  Implementing your strategy now.

Answer (score 2):

This is what semaphores are for:

```
bool waitForBlockToExecute()
{
    __block bool value = false;

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        // sleep for a bit
        sleep(1);

        value = true;

        // notify that the block is finished
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    });

    // wait for the semaphore
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(semaphore); // clean up the semaphore

    return value;
}
```

Obviously, the `dispatch_async` block would be replaced with your callback block, but I assume you get the picture from the above code.

Comment: The problem is that many APIs that are asynchronous depend on the current thread returning to the run loop. So, with those APIs, you're inviting deadlock with this approach. For an example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10868897/1312143 and how the questioner tried it and found it to deadlock.